# How do we ensure that a model generalize well in the real world

Tags: machine-learning

When we have trained a model on a training data set as well as the test set, how can we ensure that a model will generalize in the real world.I mean both the test set and the training set are a very small subset compared to what exist in the real world and there might be inherent bias in the datasets as well.

As a beginner in machine learning , it will help me and others a lot if you share the techniques to avoid the common pitfalls

Answer (score 2):

You should try out the model that you built in real world by using test data that reflect real data.

Machine learning is an iterative process, you have to try it out and see the performance.

- Your test data should be extended to reflect real life scenario that you expect it to work well.
- You might want to change your objective function sometimes, your existing objective function might not have capture some real life factor. For example, if you see your model keep making mistakes on certain type of data, you might want to penalize it more.
- Your model might not last forever, real life data might change over time and you have to tune your model to adapt to it. Your model might not have forseen some scenarios and might not know what should be the correct response to be.

Comment: Thank you for your valuation input.Can you elaborate more on how we test the accuracy of the model once in production because to know how badly it performs we need to know a ground truth(label) which won't be available because if it were , there won't be any need for a model anyways.Humans could be used to label some random sample of data from user but i am sure there must be a better approach

Comment: i'm not sure what is the best practice. One possibility is to think of what can be a possible observable. For example, if you have built a classification model to detect   dogs to reduce stray dog, report count of stray dog can an indicator of whether your model is still functioning.